# "Linux apt-get command not found" - how can I install a package in Arch Linux?

Tags: archlinux, apt-get

I am trying to install a command in a terminal window:

```
sudo -s apt-get install net-tools
```

Result:

> /bin/bash: apt-get: command not found

How can I install `apt-get` then?

I use the command below to find out My Linux distribution name and version:

```
cat /etc/*-release
```

I get this below:

```
NAME="Arch Linux"
ID=arch
PRETTY_NAME="Arch Linux"
ANSI_COLOR="0;36"
HOME_URL="https://www.archlinux.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://bbs.archlinux.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.archlinux.org/"
```

What should I do to install a command in Arch Linux?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124985/arch-linux-apt-get-update-equivalent-command/43127573#43127573  This should help you.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First of all, Arch Linux provides [a beautiful, well maintained wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Linux). You may want to read it first before working with Arch Linux. The pre-installed package manager is [Pacman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux#Pacman).

To install a package from the official repositories, you will need to use it like this:

`# pacman -S <package name>`

There is also a community-maintained version, the [Arch User Repository](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository) (AUR), for packages not part of the official repository.

Comment: thanks for the answer and the links! they are very useful :-)

Answer (score 11):

I used page *[pacman/Rosetta](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman_Rosetta)* when I moved to Arch Linux. It lists the equivalent commands for various common package managers, including [APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(software)) and [Pacman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux#Pacman).

For example:

| Action | [Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux) | [Red Hat Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux)/ [Fedora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_Linux) | [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian)/ [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) | [SLES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUSE_Linux_Enterprise)/ [openSUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSUSE) | [Gentoo Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentoo_Linux) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Install a package(s) | `pacman -S` | `dnf install` | `apt install` | `zypper install` | `emerge [-a]` |
| Remove a package(s) | `pacman -Rs` | `dnf remove` | `apt remove` | `zypper remove` | `emerge -C` |
| Search for package(s) | `pacman -Ss` | `dnf search` | `apt search` | `zypper search` | `emerge -S` |
| Upgrade Packages | `pacman -Syu` | `dnf upgrade` | `apt update; apt upgrade` | `zypper update` | `emerge -u world` |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: I don't think "converts ... common package manager commands including apt to pacman" describes what happens. That feels like "apt update" _converts_ to "pacman update", which it doesn't.

Comment: @Marcus I don't mean what you understood, the table in the link showing each command in ubuntu and Arch ,
`apt upgrade -> pacman -Syu`

Answer (score 8):

If you really want to download [APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(software)), then:

1. Install *pacaur*:

   `pacman -S pacaur`
2. Install APT, from *pacaur* (no root)

   `pacaur -S apt`
3. Add some repositories
4. Now you have a working APT on Arch Linux

Comment: is there any downside to this approach? Also I see error: target not found: pacaur on the version of Arch linux that comes with RuneAudio running on Raspberry PI.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Arch Linux does not use the [APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(software)) package system, unlike Debian-based Linuxes, like [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29). Instead, it uses the [Pacman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux#Pacman) package manager. However, you should try it out. Using Pacman myself, I never had a problem with it, and you can still use it in order to install packages that you can get with the APT package manager.

Comment: It isn't true that you can't use apt on Arch.

You can install apt from the AUR. I am working on maintaining both deb and rpm packages for a tool I develop, and one of the great things about Arch is that you can install both dpkg/apt and rpm/(yum|dnf).

However, I definitely recommend using pacaur to manage software that you aren't just testing.

Answer (score 1):

Arch Linux does not generally use the [APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(software)) package manager. It uses [Pacman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux#Pacman).

See the Arch wiki: *[Pacman](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman)*

Answer (score 0):

As [Marcus mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35343707/linux-apt-get-command-not-found-how-to-install-a-package-in-arch-linux/35343944#35343944), Pacman is the built-in package manager. However, it won't give you access to [AUR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux#Arch_User_Repository_(AUR)) packages.

- `aurman` is a nice wrapper that also searches and installs from AUR.
- `yaourt` used to be popular, but according to the AUR wiki it is insecure and not featureful.
- `aurman` [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) works almost exactly like Pacman so you can follow a Pacman guide just the same. To get `aurman`:

  ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/aurman.git
   cd aurman
   makepkg -Acs

   # Change xxx below to downloaded version
   sudo pacman -U aurman-xxx.pkg.tar.xz
  ```

Then, you can follow something like *[How to use Arch Linux package management](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-arch-linux-package-management)* which I also pasted into this Stack Exchange answer here: *[How do I install packages from the AUR?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/510/how-do-i-install-packages-from-the-aur/84216)*

`aurman` can also be found on GitHub: *[aurman - AUR helper with almost pacman syntax](https://github.com/polygamma/aurman)*

Answer (score 0):

Arch Linux does *not* use [APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(software)) (`apt` or `apt-get`). Instead, however, it uses [Pacman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux#Pacman). The syntax for Pacman is quite different than `apt-get`; it uses `-S` to install packages instead of `install`. For example, `sudo pacman -S [package]`.

Learn more at [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pacman) or maybe type `--help`. Or on the wiki: *[Pacman](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/pacman)*