# What is the 'apt-get update' equivalent command in Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, archlinux, pacman-package-manager

What is the command for Arch Linux to **update** the packages before installing a new package?

For instance, I know that in Ubuntu, I do this in a terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get <package name>
```

What about in [Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux)?

I came across a couple of versions, but they don't seem agree with each others. I can't see the consistency there.

[Example 1.](https://www.garron.me/en/go2linux/upgrade-update-arch-linux.html) (it looks tedious to me):

```
sudo pacman -Syy
sudo pacman -Su
```

[Example 2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-arch-linux-package-management):

```
sudo pacman -Sy
```

[Example 3](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=76376):

> always use "-Sy" with a "u". I.e., "pacman -Syu"
> and then "pacman -S <package>", and never "pacman -Sy <package>".

Comment: This is off topic for StackOverflow, since it's not related to software development.  I've generally found the Arch documentation to be quite good; if there's a particular document you think isn't sufficiently clear, you may want to [report a bug](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Reporting_bug_guidelines) so that the Arch folks can improve the documentation.

Comment: `pacman -Syu` https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Upgrading_packages

Comment: Copied without any attribution whatsoever at `9to5answer DOT com/arch-linux-apt-get-update-equivalent-command` (the author link is fake and just points back to the same page)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The equivalent of `apt-get update` in Arch Linux is `pacman -Syy`.

`pacman -Syu` is equivalent to `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`.

Might as well make this complete if it stays...

`pacman -S <package>` is `apt-get install <package>`.

Answer (score 2):

*Note: I agree with [larsks' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43124985/arch-linux-apt-get-update-equivalent-command/57756149#comment73329183_43124985) that the best source here is the Arch wiki.*

For example, the wiki entry *[pacman/Rosetta](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Rosetta)* covers the operations for Pacman in depth for people who previously used ("coming from"): [DNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNF_(software)) ([Red Hat Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux)/[Fedora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_Linux)), [APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(software)) ([Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian)/[Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29)), [ZYpp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZYpp) (executable `zypper`. [SUSE Linux Enterprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUSE_Linux_Enterprise) (SLES)/[openSUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSUSE)) or Portage (executable `emerge`. [Gentoo Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentoo_Linux)).

From that document, `apt update && apt upgrade` is equivalent to `pacman -Syu`.

Comment: Arch is not a good source for documentation.  Arch makes changes to the system, and then expects the users to find the changes, address the problem and write out a solution for others.  They push problems to the end user instead of taking care of it at a higher level.  But every arch admin will tout the phrase 'The best source is the Arch wiki.'.  Don't buy into it!

Comment: @Deanie Arch is really just a minimal system with package repositories. The package manager you use is not dictated by Arch (although `pacman` is the one pre-installed software, yes). The arch community documents the usage of these (independent) software components in their wiki. It's not "them" making changes, it's the end-user's wish for a bleeding-edge system and the changes made by software developers. The Arch wiki to me is an OS-agnostic source of Linux-relevant information. An example is the link I posted: it is helpful even when you migrate from Fedora to Gentoo, i.e.,it's OS-agnostic.